# 'Tag' column in a table in Excel, similar to Wordpress

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I need to use Excel as a "database programme" (even though I know there are other solutions actually built for that). Because of that, I need to find a way to create a filterable column with **TAGS/LABELS**

What I use right now is plain old table with two columns filled with comma separated values. That makes the data easily filterable (filter > search), but doesn't do the following:

1) When filtering the table by column "Furniture", offer separated values (as in "tables" and "chairs", not "tables, chairs" or "chairs, tables").
2) When adding new entries/lines to the table, offer existing tags (as in use "tables" instead of "table" under column "Furniture").

## EDIT

Let me be more specific.

I need to create a media list. Each contact is labeled with multiple tags (such as "design", "music", "tourism", "government institution") in ONE COLUMN.

E.g., Users of the media list need to filter out contacts "design". There are rows with columns "cinema, design, exhibition" and "design, tourism". I need them to be able to select under the "filter context menu" specific tags and not the full columns.

That means - not "cinema, design, exhibition" but "cinema", "design" and "exhibition".

If you're familiar with Wordpress administration, its "tags" administration works pretty rad. :)

Comment: Can you show us one example of what you want to achieve?

Comment: Douglaslps, check my edit! Does it make sense now?

Comment: To my knowledge I would say that is not possible with MS Excel.

Comment: Yes, I've just found the duplicate question: http://superuser.com/questions/642192/filter-comma-delimited-excel-column Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a very simple solution:
https://youtu.be/nnCNU6SR3jg

First column contains the filterable data.
Second column contains the tags, each tag in new row.
Then merge the data rows in the first column related to its tags as you see in the video link.
Use the auto filter.

That's all.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1122591)

Answer (score 4):

According to Douglaslps and this question I duplicated - [Filter comma-delimited Excel column](https://superuser.com/questions/642192/filter-comma-delimited-excel-column) - the thing I'm trying to achieve is not possible in Excel.

At least the problem serves as a good reminder that we should use applications to solve the problems they were designed to solve. :)

Alternative sollution (which doesn't really work for me) can be found here: [How to Label / Tag Items in a Spreadsheet](https://superuser.com/questions/405215/how-to-label-tag-items-in-a-spreadsheet)