# Excel filtering multiple columns with common header and common criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have made a Book Archive in Excel 2013 that has the data sorted like this.

**Book's Owner  ¦  Book Cover  ¦  Book Name  ¦  Author  ¦  Edition  ¦  Language  ¦  Topic  ¦  Index**

Since those are technical books only sometimes they have multiple authors so I had the idea to write the authors separated by a comma in the same columns with the idea I could have put a filter to filter them individually, something like [Filter Comma Delimited Excel Column](http://www.superuser.com/questions/642192/filter-comma-delimited-excel-column).

But I understood it being impossible, so I decided to try another approach. I separated the Author column in 5 different columns and I merged the the header as a single one.

What I want to do now is to be able to filter it by the header with a drop down list with all the authors, but with the AutoFilter function in the criteria it only display the authors that appears on the first column.

How can I make excel extend the criteria to the whole range of cells?

I'll attach some pictures to make you understand better.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would solve this using the Power Pivot add-in.  First I would split your Book Archive into two tables:
1. A new table e.g. Book Authors with just two columns, Book and Author.  If a Book has multiple Authors, it would have multiple rows.
2. The current table, with all the Authors removed.

Then I would load those two tables into Power Pivot and set the relationship between them on Name (it might successfully Auto-detect that).

Finally I would build a Pivot Table (or Flattened Pivot Table) filtering on Authors and showing details of their Books.

Comment: I don't really get what you mean, I started using excel by two weeks so I still miss some basic knowledge. Could you attach a screenshot?

Comment: Yeah maybe, but I'm not going to do a whole lot of typing ... can you share some sample data on Onedrive or similar?

Comment: http://1drv.ms/1pxlKAE

Comment: Sorry that link doesn't work - it says "Sorry, we can't open your workbook in Excel Online because it exceeds the 5 MB file size limit.
You'll need to open this in Excel." But then it wont open in Excel.  I only need a sample - cut out most of the rows.